# Points of continuity of a sequence of almost everywhere continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

The problem I am faced with is the following. Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of points that is dense in some bounded open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $n \geq 2$. Let $f_n : U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is continuous everywhere except at the points $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$. Is the pointwise limit function $f(x) := \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ continuous at some point in $U$?

I thought about trying to apply the corollary to the Baire category theorem which states that if $f_n : U \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of continuous functions then the pointwise limit is continuous on a generic subset of $U$ (i.e., the set of points where the pointwise limit is discontinuous is of first category). However, for that to work you need continuity at every point, whereas my functions are discontinuous on a (growing) finite number of points.

Edit: The actual function I am concerned with is $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log||x-a_n||}{2^{n}}$, where again $f$ is defined on an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence dense in $U$. Here $f_n$ are the partial sums. At points in the sequence $\{a_n\}$, $f(a_n)$ is defined to take  the value $-\infty$.

Comment: How about $f_n = \sum_n k 1_{\{ a_k\}}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence of points with rational coordinates,  $f_n(a_i)=1$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and let $f_n$ be $0$ at all other points. Then the hypothesis is clearly satisfied. The limit function is not continuous at any point.

Comment: I was actually writing out this example as you answered. I took a quick step away from my computer and thought about this. I will edit the question, with the exact statement that I want to prove because maybe I am missing something subtle.

Comment: @SubSpace626 Your function $f$ is not defined at the points $a_n$. It is not obvious that it has finite values at other points. Tell us what you know about $f$.

Comment: Where $f$ is not defined we say it takes the value $-\infty$. Sorry, I should have been more careful to start with.I've edited the above to reflect that.